# Any Way to Reroute Electron's Default Files?

Tags: electron

I have a portable Electron program with a file tree that confuses some of my end users; is there any way to move the files to a different directory? I don't know what I need to edit in *package.json* (or other) to make it run.

Here's my current file tree:
[current file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idRJA.png)

Potential solutions that won't work for my use case:
• mark directories as 'Hidden' - most users have "hidden files" on, so same problem
• create a .bat that targets the .exe - need to demonstrate how to start the .bat
• create a shortcut that targets the .exe - can use relative paths to target the .exe, but couldn't figure out how to target the icon
• recompile as a single .exe - need to frequently modify scripts/pages, so recompiling each time would be too time consuming
• manually create shortcuts for end-users - each app update would require me to ensure each shortcut is up-to-date

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Um, why does this directory structure confuse your users? They'd only have to launch the EXE, don't they? Also, I doubt that you can specify where the files should be located because Electron uses Chromium under the hood and my portable Chromium "installation" looks exactly the same -- the files are probably right there because they're *required* to be there.

Comment: There's apparently a learning curve to double-clicking an exe as I keep getting asked "which one do I open?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.